# When I use the text command line interface it says my login is incorect

Tags: command-line

I need to install a `.run` file. So I went to the text command line interface ( The thing that you do by pressing<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>).

I put my login information correctly but it tells me my login is incorrect.

Comment: To use command line you need to open terminal. Just type ctrl+alt+t to open terminal.

Comment: For the terminal part, look at this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/418486/what-can-i-do-with-terminal

Comment: ^^ May be he is trying to install nvidia driver file, which require to stop x server

Comment: yes i am trying to install nvidia driver because i am trying to open a .jar file that needs Open GL

Answer (score 0):

Make sure

- You are entering your login user name first (many type password on first line)
- Login user Case are correct (say your user id is `WebE` but you are providing `webe`)

You can not use drag n drop in this interface. You need to use `cd`. You can press <kbd>Tab</kbd> for auto complete

Comment: Thanks I am i do not although have capitals or any type of special characters in my username or password and what is the WebE and webe and for drag and drop for other windows not this one

Comment: @XxMomoaxX do use fullstops.

Comment: ???? what do you mean??

Answer (score 0):

it happened to me before I am sure your password does have numbers on it, when it asks for the username type your password and check that whatever you typing is on the screen,in other words   if you have to use numbers use the numbers on top of the leters and dont use the keypad numbers for some reason they sometimes do not work in ttys

Comment: I changed my password to all letters and still the same problem